# Debug .net chart control

Tags: vb.net, charts, nullreferenceexception

I have an issue with a little charting program I am builing, using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

I get an error message which is:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll
```

Since the error is not (directly) in my code, it is only trigerred at the end of the sub, which makes it incredibely hard to debug.

I have tried spamming Application.DoEvents everywhere, but that lead me nowhere.

Is there anyway to dive in DataVisualization.dll, in order to better understand what causes it to crash?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Maxime

Comment: You should post your code that shows the usage of the Charting namespace, so everyone can see if there is anything you are missing.

Comment: It's over 500 lines, and very badly done (I'm a pro of spaghetti code).
I have solved my issue (I have a function to generate annotations text, and in some cases, it could return Nothing, which caused the crash), but it took a lot of grunt work, and I am still really interested in knowing how this could have been done more cleverly.

Comment: If everything works and you want feedback and improvements, you could head on over to [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can debug the dotnet framework sources - the details how to accomplish this is explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx).

But in many cases I found it more helpful just to see the source code where the exception occurs (stack trace) with the 3rd party tool .NET Reflector.